# Difference between reference and packagereference elements (c#)

Tags: c#, package, system.net

I see that certain system packages (e.g. System.Net.Http) are referenced using **PackageReference** elements, while other are referenced using **Reference** elements.

What is the difference between the two options? Are the two interchangeable?

Which one is more preferable?